# Is the jetty maven artifact jboss-jetty?

Tags: java, maven, jetty

I would like to embed Jetty into my application. Is the maven artifact jboss-jetty? If not, what is it?

Comment: I do think you know what you are saying ? it's like I would like to have Toyota but has it got two or four legs? I think you be after  maven-jetty-plugin http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Jetty 6 (`org.mortbay.jetty`) there is a special `jetty-embedded` artifact.

Jetty 7 (`org.eclipse.jetty`) doesn't have such an artifact, so that you have to use combination of different artifacts (at least `jetty-server` and `jetty-servlet`).

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you read the [Maven Jetty Plugin Configuration Guide](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin)

Comment: That guide is for the Maven plugin and doesn't provide any info on the artifact(s) needed for embedding Jetty in an application.

Answer (score 0):

You just add the below depandency  and the rest will be downloaded when you will fire "mvn install"

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <webAppSourceDirectory>WebContent</webAppSourceDirectory>
                <!-- <classesDirectory>WebContent/WEB-INF/classes</classesDirectory> -->
                <!-- Redeploy every 1 seconds if changes are detected, 0 for no automatic 
                    redeployment -->
                <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <!-- reload manually by hitting enter on console -->
                <reload>manual</reload>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                    <descriptor>WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml</descriptor>
                </webApp>
                <connectors>
                    <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector">
                        <port>8080</port>
                        <maxIdleTime>600000</maxIdleTime>
                    </connector>
                </connectors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Change the value accordingly.

Cheers!